# Calculating a Total for a Grid

Tags: rally

I have a grid of the which has actual time as one of its columns.  How can I add the rows up to get the total actual time similar to the way it is done on the track team status page.
Edit:

I am currently trying to find the sum using this var sum = grid.getStore().sum('Actuals');, however when I run it, I get this error on the console:
 Uncaught ReferenceError: grid is not defined

I have also tried using this piece of code that I found online:

```
      var tasks = [];
            var users = [];
            that = this
            if (data.length ===0) {
            this._createGrid();  //to refresh grid when no items in iteration
       }
            Ext.Array.each(this.tasks, function(task) {
                        var owner = task.get('Owner'); 
                        var total;
                                Ext.Array.each(data, function(actual){
                                     //some tasks have no owner. If this condition is not checked Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_refObjectName' of null 
                                    if (owner && actual.get('User')._refObjectName === owner._refObjectName) { 
                                        total = actual.get('Actuals');

                                    }
                                });
                                var t  = {
                            FormattedID: task.get('FormattedID'),
                            _ref: task.get("_ref"), 
                            Name: task.get('Name'),
                            Estimate: task.get('Actuals'),
                            Owner: (owner && owner._refObjectName) || 'None',
                            TaskEstimates: total
                        };
                                tasks.push(t);
             });
```

},

but when I try to print total or taskestimate or attempt to find a specific part of tasks (tasks[i][j]) I either get no data or an error

Comment: You should be more specific. What language are you using, what have you tried, what are your problems.

Answer (score 0):

See a not-treegrid code in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459909/the-experimental-hierarchical-tree-for-rally) for an example of how to create a row in a grid that sums up values in a specific column (e.g. Estimate)

```
 columnCfgs: [
                {
                    xtype: 'templatecolumn',text: 'ID',dataIndex: 'FormattedID',width: 100,
                    tpl: Ext.create('Rally.ui.renderer.template.FormattedIDTemplate'),
                    summaryRenderer: function() {
                        return "Estimate Total"; 
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: 'Estimate',dataIndex: 'Estimate',
                    summaryType: 'sum',
                }
```